# Default background color in Textedit

Tags: preferences, defaults, textedit

How do I set default background color in Textedit?

`Preferences -> New Document -> Font` doesnt help.

That black on white isn't too good in nights.

Answer (score 2):

1. CMD + T
2. Adjust document color.
3. Adjust text color.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to set a custom *default* page and text colour (OP's question) - it only defines them for the current document.

Comment: Not working. New files keep showing up in the default default fonts. Why white background? this is not a sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [WriteRoom](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/writeroom). It's based on TextEdit but has a few additional features like customizable themes.

Comment: For plain text editing, [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (free) can use BBEdit themes.

Answer (score 0):

While Louis told you the literal way to change your font and background color, the cursor will remain unchanged, making the editor practically unusable.  That's just the Apple way.

Your best bet is to switch to another editor (like in Lauri's response) or simply tint your background to something less glaring than hard-white.

I know this ain't the answer you're looking for, but this is a computer for people who do NOT want the complexity of customization.  Sorry.

Comment: Aw, I see I hurt some MacNut's feelings. But despite many people's unconditional love, Apple products are designed to work one way: the Apple way. It's like Henry Ford, "Any customer can have a car painted any color that he wants so long as it is black." The truth hurts.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not trolling because I'm on StackExchange, but saying that OS X only works in the "Apple way" and isn't customizable is only a thought that is reinforced by a group of people who got mad after trying to open a .exe file the first time they used a Mac.

Comment: @Louis: Prove me wrong; how do you change change the color of the cursor in TextEdit?  You might even get some points for a correct answer here.

Comment: You can't change the cursor color in TextEdit you can't in NotePad (windows) or gedit (linux). So I guess having those kind of text editors by default in your OS is not really the "Apple way" but everyone's way. If you want those features you're gonna have to use another text editor because those those kind of programs are just simple text editors that exist so you can quickly edit any text file such as config files, which is why the default font in them is monospaced. I wouldn't know what programs to recommend to the OP because I'm a software engineer. I don't write anything other than code.

Comment: OS X is 100% POSIX compliant, which gives you access to a limitless number of tools that lets you do anything you could possibly want with any computer. The fact that you would even suggest that OS X is not for people who want the complexity of customization could only mean that you are either trolling, or that you have absolutely no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextMate.

You get all the simplicity of TexEdit (and you can easily disable all the little noise). I even find its startup speed better than TextEdit's.