# White on black in TextEdit

Tags: macos, textedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default background color in Textedit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70216/default-background-color-in-textedit)

Is there any way to get text displayed in white and the background be black in TextEdit in plain text mode?

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>CMD</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Adjust document color.
3. Adjust text color.

Comment: Cool, any way to set that as default? I tried going through the preferences but the font picker seems broken (i.e. the colors don't update or anything, and when I reopen TextEdit it's black on white again).

Comment: Hi, the color picker works for me. But I don't seem to be able to make it default.

Comment: Yea, I meant it works (even though the color picker doesn't show any visual feedback, the actual window color changes), but setting it as default doesn't.

Comment: You could save a blank document with those colours, then mark it as stationary pad (use Get Info in Finder), and start every new document from this one.

Comment: Nice trick. Never know we can do that.

Comment: Not a real solution as the cursor will still be black, rendering the editor nearly unusable.  And the cursor color can NOT be changed. If you wanted a computer that you can customize to your personality, you should have bought a Windoze or Linux machine.